# Is it possible to use FlurryAPI within a static library?

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton, analytics, static-libraries

I'm working on a static library to distribute to iOS developers, and I'd like to incorporate an analytics library like [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) to know more about how users are interacting with it. My concern is that if app developers are already using Flurry in their apps and the library initializes a new session, it will clobber their existing session.

My first idea is to subclass `FlurryAPI`, but it's hard to say whether or not it will do any good without knowing the implementation details.

Does anyone have any experience with this or ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received a response from Flurry support saying that it's against their TOS to include Flurry in a static library for use in other apps. Looking into modifying and using the [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/) SDK instead.

Answer (score 0):

You activate Flurry in the AppDelegate (Most preferred way), check there for an existing session?

Or create a method that you need implement in the AppDelegate wich checks and or create a new session.

Comment: I know that's how you'd do it for a regular app, but I want to include this code in a static library for use in *other* apps.